# Putting a struct member inside of a separate variable to clean up code and helping me understand how the code would look formatted differently

Tags: c, struct, primitive-types

In C, instead of just listing out a struct variable such as `((struct listing*)p)`, what kind of primitive type should my variable be in order to hold this and how would it look?

For example, I currently have this function inside of my program:

```
int price_comparator(const void* p, const void *q){

    float price1 = ((struct listing*)p)->price;
    float price2 = ((struct listing*)q)->price;

    return (price1 - price2);
}
```

This does work, however, I would like to format this function in different ways. One way I would like to clean this up a bit would be to put "((struct listing*)p)" into a variable before putting it into the price1 variable.

I'd like to try something like this:

```
struct structOne = ((listing*)p);
```

or

```
void structOne = ((listing*)p);
```

but neither of those are working from what I can tell. Also, the parenthesis are confusing me a little bit inside of:

```
 ((struct listing*)q)->price
```

I'd like to see it formatted differently, such as when it doesn't have the arrow pointing to "price" in order to see how it works more clearly.

My stuct has already been created at the beginning of my program as follows:

```
struct listing {
   float latitude, longitude, price;
};
```

But this is not needed to answer my question

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pointers to structure` instead of `void pointers`:

```
int price_comparator (struct listing *p, struct listing *q)
{
    return (p->price - q->price);
}
```

Comment: Not possible if the comparator is part of a generic interface like `qsort` which requires the parameters to be `const void *`

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand is that you want to access the struct without using the arrows and what data type to use.

First: your datatype should be of type struct listing * instead of void *.

Second: To make typing more easier you should declare your struct using typedef

```
typedef struct { 
    float latitude, longitude, price;
} listing;
```

This will make using your struct easier like instead of using:

```
struct listing x = {2.3, 3.5, 11.0};
```

You can do this:

```
listing x = {2.3, 3.6, 11.5};
```

Third: To access a pointer to struct without the arrows from void * you can do this :

```
float price1 = (*((listing *) p)).price;
float price2 = (*((listing *) q)).price;
return price1 - price2;
```

I hope that answered your question.

Comment: `*p` is not possible when `p` has type `const void *`

Comment: @M.M 
(*((listing *) p)).price is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can make local pointers of the right type:

```
int price_comparator(const void* p, const void *q)
{
    struct listing const *p1 = p;
    struct listing const *q1 = q;

    return p1->price - q1->price;
}
```

Cast is not necessary here as we have specified the type for p1 and q1 already .